# Sigma Algebra: Etymology

Tags: abstract-algebra, measure-theory, boolean-algebra

Why do we talk of **sigma** algebras in measure theory. As far as I know sigma is related to the countability. But what does it stand for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got it: An algebra in the sense of sets is meant to be a boolean algebra w.r.t. union, intersection, complementation plus the empty set and the universe. In this setting goin to countability raises both intersections and unions so theres no need to be more precise so we can simply say sigma algebra without refering to intersections or unions.

Sigma in this setting then has the meaning of countable rather than "summe" as the german word for union...

Besides talkin of countable complementations has no meaning, anyway.

Comment: Rather, $\sigma$ tends to stand for «countable» in this context. Other examples are $\sigma$-finite, $\sigma$-compact, and so on.

Comment: So what does it stand for - sigma=sequence?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Sorry, I forgot my own question...